# JSON Fetch PHP array using File_get_contents

Tags: php, arrays, json, file-get-contents

I am trying to fetch the below json content. The output of the json is like this. i want the below json to convert to php array.

PHP

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
$requestData = json_decode($requestBody,true);
    if($requestData){
        $no = $requestData["no[]"];
    } else {
        $no = 0;
    }echo $no;
```

previous page Html

```
<input name="no[]" type="checkbox"/>
```

The above code returns an empty array. How is it possible to convert the above JSON to php object array.

Comment: There is no JSON in your whole question.

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple `<input name="no[]" type="checkbox"/>` in your html and you wish to get all data into a php array after html page is submitted?

Comment: Are you submitting an HTML form, whose data you want to capture as an array? As I am unable to see any json data in your given code. Let me know what's the value of `var_dump($requestBody);` there?

Comment: `The output of the json is like this` what output? do a `var_dump($requestData)` and add it in the question

Comment: Andy Hui please wake up and answer all the questions asked in different comments

Comment: @EngCy i have using Handlebar.js to loop multiple **<input name="no[]" type="checkbox"/>** i wonder how to pump in data into php array. This are my var dump result `string(2) "{}" {"count":0,"invoices":[]}` And sorry for late reply, i having car accident yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you're posting your form data as JSON and not as a regular form. One way to do this is serializing your form as a JSON object and then send it through an ajax request:

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());
//AJAX POST request here
```

Then on your server code, `$requestData` will contain a nice php array of all posted data, which means that if your "`no`" form data is an array, you will have to iterate over its values, you cannot access them using `$requestData['no[]']` :

```
foreach($requestData['no'] as $no) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Are you saying any major browser would actually care about `enctype='application/json'`, and convert the form data to JSON before submitting …?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your comment, I just checked W3C and saw that their draft about this feature was actually rejected. I'm going to update my answer